# Python 3 - files imported as dictionary, but the values are lists - how to resolve?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm importing files from a folder into python as a dictionary, with the 
**key** = filename and **value** = file contents.

e.g.,

```
mydict = {'File1': ['this is a string as a list'], 
'File2': ['second string in file 2 is also a list']}
```

Whereas what I'd like is to have:

```
mydict = {'File1': 'this is a string as a list', 'File2:': '...'}
```

I also want to count the following strings: "string", "this is", "second string" to output it in a datastructure. I'm guessing I'd need to use `counter` from `collections` to do that - but do I first need to `tokenize` my values?

Code to import text into dictionary:

```
filenames = os.listdir('.')
file_dict = {}
for file in filenames:
    with open(file) as f:
        items = [i.strip() for i in f.read().split(",")]
    file_dict[file.replace(".txt", "")] = items

print(file_dict)
```

To make the values all lowercase (doesn't work since they are in list):

```
#convert dictionary to lower case
def lower_dict(d):
   new_dict = dict((k, v.lower()) for k, v in d.items())
   return new_dict
print(lower_dict(file_dict))
```

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are splitting the input when you load it:

```
items = [i.strip() for i in f.read().split(",")]
```

If you want just the file contents, then you can just use:

```
items = f.read()
```

If you still want to trim whitespaces around commas (`,`), then you can recombine them with `str.join`

```
items = ','.join([i.strip() for i in f.read().split(",")])    # This will reinsert commas
items = ''.join([i.strip() for i in f.read().split(",")])     # This will not
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. Quick question though - I have lots of \n 's in my values. Will this impact things like counting strings, or is it just how python displays out in console? For instance, if I want to count the number of times "texas" comes up, butI can see in the console the value is shown as \nconsole - will it not count?

Comment: `\n` is the escape code for a newline. This probably wont impact counting if you are just searching for the word, however it may be an issue in other applications.

Comment: You're right - it doesn't impact counting (just checked), thanks so much!